# Two different function signatures in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, signature, keyword-argument, args

Why are there in Pycharm two different 'styles' of presenting the function signature?
For example numpy.arange:

at the top of the popup:

```
def arange(start: Optional[int] = None, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> ndarray
```

below (the same as in the documentations [1](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)):

```
arange([start,] stop [,step], dtype=None,*, like=None)
```

How should I understand `*args` and `**kwargs` in `numpy.arange` signature in PyCharm?

In what sense can i pass an arbitrary number of unnamed arguments (`*args`), and an arbitrary number of keyword arguments(`**kwargs`)?
When I write, for example:

```
A = numpy.arange(start=0, stop=1.1, step=0.1, blabla='asdf')
```

I get a

> TypeError: arange() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blabla'

Comment: The first format is Python's standard type hinting syntax. The second is is more descriptive documentation.

Comment: You should refer to numpy specific documentation as primary resource.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why would you **want** to pass arbitrary arguments, if they wouldnt be used? Maybe you should learn by defining _your own function_ with those arguments.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm learning python and just would like to understand what python and pycharm is telling me - how I could use the hints to improve my coding.

Comment: They tell you approximately the same thing, but numpy only accepts specific keyword arguments, which Pycharm wouldn't know about from only inspecting the function signature. Thus, its documentation is more explicit